# Create Diagonal image from bitmap image in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, bitmapimage, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I want to make a diagonal/ triangle shape image from bitmap source without using any polygon control, how to do this in windows phone.[image]

Comment: What do you mean, you want to "make it?" Make it where? Dynamically? Why not with a shape?

Comment: You could make a custom effect (using the Nokia Imaging SDK) that masks out a triangle shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm what do you mean without using any polygon controls?

You can create a WriteableBitmap, and draw on it with any tools you prefer. If you want to avoid all additional tools you can call set/get pixel methods and for loops.

When you are happy with your WriteableBitmap you can create a BitmapImageSource and then call .AsBitmap() on your WriteableBitmap. With that complete you can then use the whole imaging SDK chain.

Edit: You can find the .AsBitmap method in Nokia.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime namespace.